# ASP jQuery .load method not triggering controller action method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a list in a partial view using AJAX and JQuery using Entity framework. The intended functionality is for the user to be able to click on an action link on the navbar, which in turn sets off a JQuery event that injects a list from a controller action method into a partial view. For this, I am using the .load() jQuery method. However, every time I click on the action link, the jquery event properly fires, but the partial view is never called by the controller method.

By looking at the newtork tab in Chrome, I can see the following:[network stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiX4i.jpg)

Here is my setup:

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult ListeArtistes()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
    Debug.WriteLine("Liste artistes called");
    return PartialView(db.Artistes.ToList());
}
```

In _Layout.cshtml, I have an action link with an id:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Artistes", "", "", new { id = "Artistes" })
```

At the bottom of _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/MediaScripts.js"></script>
```

And finally, in my MediaScripts.js:

```
function onNav_ListeArtistes() {
    $("#viewPlaceHolder").load('@Url.Action("ListeArtistes", "Home")')
        .on("click", function () { artisteListeAlbum(); });

}
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks for any hint!

-Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor code doesn't work when  you put it into your JS file as you did with **MediaScripts.js** :

```
function onNav_ListeArtistes() {
    $("#viewPlaceHolder").load('@Url.Action("ListeArtistes", "Home")') // <- This will not work.
        .on("click", function () { artisteListeAlbum(); });
}
```

If you need to pass some data to your JS file, just store the value into your CSHTML by using `data-*` attribute like this:

```
<body data-artistes-url='@Url.Action("ListeArtistes", "Home")'>
<!-- other markups -->
</body>
```

Then into your JS file do this:

```
function onNav_ListeArtistes() {
    $("#viewPlaceHolder").load($('body').data('artistes-url')) <-- here you retrieve the URL stored into data-artistes-url attributes.
        .on("click", function () { artisteListeAlbum(); });
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for the tip :) However, is there a way to do it so it's independent from the view? Instead of using Url.Action, I have tried a specific path to the controller action from the script: $('#liste').load("/Home/Artistes"); but it doesn't work. I want to be able to simpy inject html content into a view and manage the rest on the server side...

Comment: You can directly paste the relative URL into your JS file but using this method is more maintainable because if your controller's action name changed you don't need to change the JS file.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks again I was banging my head against the wall on this one.